# IndexOutOfRangeException when Using loop to create jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

when trying to use a loop to create a jagged array, but what happens is I get an IndexOutOfRangeException when i and j are 0. Here is the code

```
        double[,][] coords = new double[,][] { };
        for (int i = 0; i <= p; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= q; j++)
            {
                coords[i, j] = new double[4] { (4 things in here) };
            }
        }
```

I have read this: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/360615 but do not know how to apply it to this.

Solution: changed from "double[,][] coords = new double[,][] { };" to "double[,][] coords = new double[p,q][];" Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How are `p` and `q` initialized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate your array size, from your code I assume this would be correct size.

```
double[,][] coords = new double[p+1,q+1][];
```

Comment: +1 ,  and also he need change the i < = p and j < =q  to  i < p and j < q ?

Comment: I can't tell if he needs that, he should know, but if he does, array size will be just [p,q]